# Prioritize fields which start with search term using Sphinx (Thinking Sphinx) - or another full-text search engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, full-text-search, solr, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I'm using sphinx and thinking sphinx to search a customer database. The customer metadata (emails, tels etc) are spread across multiple tables and sphinx indexes all notes on customers etc etc. The problem I'm having is that I want text fields which START with the search term to be displayed first in searches. i.e. a search for "hods" should return results in the order:

- Hods

  The Hods

  Hodson

  Methods

which means should prioritize (roughly in this order):

- Start of phrase

  Complete words

  Start of words

i've tried to achieve this with a composite search term (e.g. "^hods | hods | hods* | *hods").

Somthing like this can ensure I finds all the appropriate results - but doesn't seem to affect how they are ranked!! I can't find anything useful in the documentation either!!

Any ideas? Is this possible with Sphinx? Any other search solutions where this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Sphinx 1.10 introduces new [ranking mode](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#api-func-setrankingmode): `SPH_RANK_SPH04`.

You can set ranking mode with `thinking-sphinx` although it is not documented on its home page. I can't recall right now how I did it exactly, but it was very similar to setting other search params.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used ThinkingSphinx, but I [boost query terms](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_3_2/queryparsersyntax.html#Boosting%20a%20Term) all of the time in Lucene/Solr.  There should be a similar mechanism in most searching tools.

Answer (score 0):

```
(e.g. "^hods | hods | hods* | *hods")
```

this query does not prioritize results. the above query only decides what to fetch.

If you have to prioritize, you have to use ranking modes .. or sort modes probably.